# How can I implement algorithm for finding square root of x

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, math

I have an experiment I have to do and in it I have to make an algorithm to find the square root of x.
This is how I'm supposed to do it:

[image]

I'm able to do it till step (b.) but I can't make up how I'm supposed to do the rest.

This is where I am right now:

```
# Algorithm for finding the sqr of x = 16

# Guess
g = 9
print("Step1: The guess is 9 and it's square is " + str(g * g))
```

I'm new to Python so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What searches did you do? You can search stackoverflow.com, or just use google.com

Comment: Did you look up how to loop? (for step d)

Comment: @quamrana I tried to search on google using the same question I asked here. Yet at-least for me what I found I couldn't understand.. Or maybe I just don't know what I should be asking.. So that's why I came here to ask for a help on more of a personal level because It has helped me before like this and I hope it can be done again.. I hope you understand

Comment: @trincot No I haven't yet but I think I can figure that out later. Or you can link me to somewhere or tell me how I'd need to do that. Because I do know how I can make simple loops but I don't know if those are the kinds of loop I'd have to make

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: You should take the exercise point by point. If there is a part you don't know how to do it, then research that particular thing. We expect more effort from your side.

Comment: Hmm, it just looks to me like you are treating this website as a code writing service. We appreciate users who have put *some* effort into working on their problem themselves.

Comment: @wwii Thank you and I understand and I will surely be doing as you've said. It was something I needed

Comment: @quamrana
I understand what you mean and I swear my intention isn't to use it as to just copy paste and be done with my work, I'm and was just confused and I honestly didn't even know the question I was asking was the right one. It's never my intention to just blindly copy what others have said or provided I tend to learn from it as well.. I'm sorry and I'll make sure to go through the tutorials and take it step by step as you guys have suggested to me.
Thank you for your time ^^

Comment: @trincot I understand and as I said above I'll be sure to learn and give more effort from my side :). Thank you

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You really should try harder to do your own homework, but here you go.

```
g = 9
x = 16  
c = 0

if g**2-x <= 0.000001:
    print(f'The guess is {g} and its square is {g**2}')
    print(f'It took {c} steps to find the square root of {x}')
else:
    while g**2-x > 0.000001:
        print(f'The guess is {g} and its square is {g**2}')
        g = ((g+(x/g)) / 2)
        c+=1
    print(f'It took {c} steps to find the square root of {x}')
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll be sure to check out what the other users have told me and what you said. I'll also study this code and learn from it. I'm not just doing it to copy and paste I simply just didn't know if what I am asking is even correct or where should I even begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `while` loop in your code , with `while` you are able to tell your code to ***do somth until somth happen*** .

For example in your situation , the question says that `until square =g*g close enough to x`.

So you need somth like below:

```
...
while( (square - x) < 0.01 ):
  ...
  #here you have to implement other steps
```

`0.01` is just an example if you wanna do it more accurate you can use `0.001` or `0.0001` etc.

Comment: Oh, I understand. Thank you for this. It's cleared my mind a lot on how it should've been approached